# Get User by loginname using powershell

Tags: 2013, powershell

We have the following script that was running on sharepoint 2010 where we had clasic windows authentication.

When we moved to SP 2013, the authentication was changed to Claims.

The following code doesnt work anymore on Sp 2013

```
$spsite = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("https://mysite.com/");
$web = $spsite.openweb("/subsite1/subsite2/")
$removeUser = $web.AllUsers["domainname\username"];
```

I have to add the claims thing to make it work

```
$spsite = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("https://mysite.com/");
$web = $spsite.openweb("/subsite1/subsite2/")
$removeUser = $web.AllUsers["i:0#.w|domainname\username"];
```

How can I change this to make it work without the claim thingy!

Comment: You may want to use the `SiteUsers` collection rather than the `AllUsers` collection depending on the requirements. `SiteUsers` has the largest set of principals.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this variant, replacing the AllUsers lookup with EnsureUser

```
$spsite = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("https://mysite.com/")
$web = $spsite.openweb("/subsite1/subsite2/")
$removeUser = $web.EnsureUser("domainname\username")
```

Or, if you do not wish to add the user to the site even to then delete him/ her, you can build on this functionality (could probably be improved a great bit):

```
$loginName = "domainname\username"
$users = Get-SPUser -Web $web.Url

foreach($user in $users)
{
    if($user.LoginName.Contains($loginName))
    {
         $removeUser = $user
         break
    }
}
```

Or, as [this guy](http://paddleshift.wordpress.com/2011/12/19/powershell-commands-with-claims-authentication/) has done, implement a supporting method:

```
$m = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPClaimProviderManager]::Local
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ea silentlycontinue 
Function Get-SPClaim {
    param ([string]$user)
    $claim = New-SPClaimsPrincipal -identity $user -IdentityType "WindowsSamAccountName"
    return $m.EncodeClaim($claim)
}
```

that you can use like:

```
$userWithClaim = get-SPClaim($loginName)
$removeUser = $web.AllUsers[$userWithClaim]
```

Comment: as far as I know ensureuser will add the user if it doesnt exist and I dont want that, I just want to know if the user exists or not to remove it later in the script.

Comment: Yupp it will, but it is also one of your easiest way to get a reference to the user. If you do not want to add the user you can see my update

Comment: Booo, I found the same thing but didn't see your update x).

Comment: @CameronVerhelst Haha, sometimes you need to be fast and furious!

Comment: When it concerns StackExchange reputation, definitely ;)

Comment: the fight for the points!

Comment: It might sound dumb, but I would avoid `string.Contains()`, or at least add some more tests. because some names might be contained in longer names. for example `DOMAIN\bob` is contained in `DOMAIN\bobby`

Comment: @itsho You have a very valid point. Thats why I have the second part of my answer, where you use a helper method to get the actual claims identity

Comment: @Robert Lindgreen: I was oringinally using $web.EnsureUser method to add a user to SharePoint group `code`{ $siteUser = $web.EnsureUser($siteOwner);
 $group = $Global:SiteName + " Owners";
 set-SPUser -Identity $siteUser -Web $web -Group $group ;
 $web.Update() ; }  `code` . When I tried to use the claims identity to add the user to the group, it was failing with an error "set-SPUser : You must specify a valid user object or user identity."

Comment: @Nate `web.EnsureUser` is in the later patches also supporting Claims, at least that is what I have seen